# Google fonts and twitter bootstrap 3: where should I load the fonts, and how to use it in css file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, google-font-api

I am trying to customize a Bootstrap 3 based theme,
but I am having difficulties in styling it using Google fonts.

I want to use the Lora font available in Google Fonts, and the head of my page contains:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- check meaning of these 
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Luca Cerone" >
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    -->
    <title>site title</title>

    <!--- add google fonts here -->
    <!--- Google  fonts Lora -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora%3A400%2C400italic%2C700%2C700italic%7CBitter%3A400&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />

    <!--- This is Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">   

    <!--- personal styles should always be below bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
```

At the beginning of `css/stlye.css` I placed:

```
* {
    -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-border-sizing: border-box;
    border-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

and ideally I would like the Lora font to be used on all my pages.

However, when I try to load a page in a browser and check with chromium developers tools, the font family appears stricken-out and it seems to me that a serif font is used, but not `Lora`.

What am I doing wrong and how could I fix this?

Comment: the other props, like font-size, or font-weight show up in the back?

Comment: I am not sure.. in some places in html { defined in bootstrap.css appears font-family: "Helvetica" .. .in other 'Lora' is stricken out....

Comment: btw the font change size, but it doesn't look a 17px to me.. I just chose it because like this is a decent sized font...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working locally, use http:// instead of the protocol-less //
The Google font's aren't loading now...

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora%3A400%2C400italic%2C700%2C700italic%7CBitter%3A400&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Comment: Unfortunately the result didn't change... (however in production should I use // or http?)

Comment: In production // is fine. Then it will work for both http and https traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the font to the `html` and `body` tag instead like this:

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

And yes, keep the `http:` before the google font link.

And also, if your site **uses SSL certificate** (https://yourdomain.com) then use `https:` for all internal as well as external links on your site but if your site **does not use any SSL certificate** (http://yourdomain.com) then use `http` for all links in your site.